# Print adressbook from iOS without computer

Tags: iphone, ipad, contacts, printing

My father is switching from a PC to an iPad - everything works perfectly and no problems so far.

But he still keeps a laptop where he has his addresses in a spreadsheet which he can print. He would be happy to move his contacts to the iPad, but he still want's to print them to put them next to the telephone.

I only found solutions which involve a pc or Mac or the iCloud website to print contacts, =which adds complications to the process.

Is there a way (possibly an app?) which makes it possible to print the adressbook to an aiprint printer?

Answer (score 1):

'A2Z Contacts' app does that. Free version allows printing 5 addresses, so you can try it out. Full version costs $1.99.